# SAS if condition inside macro not working as expected

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have the following macro, but the 'if' condition is not evaluating to true. What did I do wrong?

```
%macro test;
 data have;
 a="kg";
 %if a=kg %then %do; b= "bc" ; %end;
 %else %do; b="gf"; %end;
 run;
 %mend;
 %test;
```

Comment: There's no reason for macro logic here at all, so is this because it's a test or is this your actual problem?

Comment: Victor - I think you made the same confusion in the linked answer (%IF and IF); if not, please clarify what's different and @ me and I can reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you've posted here, there is no need for macro logic. Changing it to IF/THEN works fine.

**Option 1:**

```
%macro test;
 data have;
 a="kg";
 if a="kg" then 
    b= "bc" ;
else    
   b="gf";
 run;

 title 'Test1';
  proc print data=have;
 run;
 title;
 %mend;
 %test;
```

Comment: I don't disagree with your answer, but I think it's not useful to post most of it; until/unless clarified, anyway, OP almost certainly is confusing %if and if and that suffices.  The rest is just confusing to most users at that level (again, unless OP clarifies).

Comment: I don't think VVALUEX is useful in this setting.  I get "ERROR: The function VVALUEX referenced by %SYSFUNC, %QSYSFUNC, or %SYSCALL cannot be used within the MACRO function/call-routine interfaces."

Comment: Agreed, will delete second answer.